# Is calling a "private" variable from a parent class (as a child class) violating Encapsulation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand more about the scopes of python variables.

As of now, I do not want to break or violate encapsulation on variables that are declared to be private i.e., "self._variable".

I was wondering whether if it would be breaking encapsulation if a child class directly calls a variable from its parent class. For example:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__():
        self._randomVariable = ''
class Child(Parent):
    def__init__():
        super().__init__()
    def doSomething():
        self._randomVariable = 'Test'
```

Does Chid.doSomething() technically break encapsulation for directly calling self._randomVariable in its method even if it is a child class?

I couldn't find anything that was Python specific about encapsulation but rather stuff based on Java. Is it the same idea between Java and Python?

Comment: `_randomValue` is a `protected` attribute. So no. If it was `__randomValue`, then it would be.

Comment: Can you expand on what protected attributes mean and what the difference between two "_" as opposed to one?

Comment: additionally don't forget - all those _ and __ are only convention - the code would work even without them - they just show your intention to the code reader

Comment: @Drako In case of `_`, yes it's a convention. But not for `__` since python will do name-mangling for those attributes and try to hide them.

Comment: @Drako Right, I understand. I thought it'd be good practice to keep practicing encapsulation whenever because from what I understand, other languages would throw errors.

Comment: @GhostArk Read this: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/private-and-protected-access-modifiers-in-python

Comment: @rdas Will do! Thank you so much for your time and resources!

Comment: @Drako: not exactly. `_` attributes are just marked as protected, while `__` ones haves their name *mangled* with the class name. So when a child class uses a `_` variable from its parent, they share the same attribute, while they would be different with `__`. For that reason `_` are said to be protected and `__` are said private.

Comment: true @rdas - I meant that you can often see code without _ and __ - still working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encapsulation is not as big of a deal in Python as it is in most other languages (Java, C++, et cetera), and you really shouldn't worry about it too much. In the Python community, we have this principle that "we are all consenting adults here".

What this means is that it's on your responsibility if you go and mess around with someone else's code, but also don't prevent others from messing with your code if they really know what they're doing. For this reason, there isn't really `private` and `protected` in Python, and you shouldn't worry about them the same way you do in Java.

But as it's become clear by now, there is still some sort of privacy with underscores. So, what are they usually used for?

#### Single underscore prefixed variables (e.g. `self._var`)

These are used for both private *and* protected variables. Prefixing your variable with an underscore is (mostly) a *convention*, which simply tells the reader that "this variable is used internally by this class, and should not be accessed from the outside". Well, if your subclasses need it, they may still use it. And if you need it from outside of the class, you may still use it. But it's on your responsibility, make sure you don't break anything.

There are some other minor effects too, such as `from module import *` not importing underscore prefixed variables, but the convention of privacy is the main point.

#### Double underscore prefixed variables (e.g. `self.__var`)

Also known as "dunder" (double-under) variables, these are used for *name mangling*. The idea is that if you have a common variable name and you're afraid that subclasses might use the same variable name for their internal stuff, you can use double underscore prefix to secure your variable from being overwritten accidentally. This way your `self.__var` becomes `self._BaseClassName__var`, and your subclass's `self.__var` becomes `self._SubClassName__var`. Now they won't overlap.

And while the effect can be used to simulate other languages' `private`, I recommend you not to. Again, we are all consenting adults here, just mark your variable "private" with a single underscore, and I won't touch it unless I really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me change your program a little bit to fix some issues :

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__randomVariable = 'Test1'
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def doSomething(self):
        self.__randomVariable = 'Test2'
```

I added `self` to the methods as first arguments since that is required when you define a method.

I changed the assignment in the parent class to `'Test1'` instead of `''` just for the sake of the example.

I also used `__randomVariable` with double underscores, since your question is about private variables, and private variables require two underscores. In Python private variables are not really private, but a mechanism of "name mangling" is used to turn them in a variable named `_Parent.__randomVariable` or `_Child.__randomVariable` depending on the class in which they are being declared.

Regarding the scope. If you would refer to `self.__randomVariable` it would refer only to the private variable named `__randomVariable` as defined in that class. In fact in your case there would be two different such private variables. There would be the one defined in the superclass, which because of the mechanism of "name mangling" in fact gets stored as `_Parent.__randomVariable`. And there is the one defined in the subclass, which gets stored as `_Child.__randomVariable`. So in your example, your child class is in fact NOT accessing the variable from its parent class; it instead defines a new private variable for the instance of the child class.

Here is some sample code to illustrate what would happen if you use the above definitions:

```py
c = Child()
print(c._Parent__randomVariable)
# prints Test1, i.e. the value assigned in the parent class
c.doSomething()
# calling doSomething will execute the assignment in the subclass
print(c._Parent__randomVariable)
# still prints Test1, i.e. the private variable in the parent class
# did not get reassigned in the method doSomething
print(c._Child__randomVariable)
# This one prints Test2, so in fact what happened is that a new
# private attribute was created in the subclass.
```

Hence, in this piece of code there is no "breach of encapsulation" since it creates different private instance variables in the parent and the child class. That being said, private instance variables are not really "encapsulated" since you can always access them (even though you are not supposed to), when you know the mechanism of name mangling. This is what I did in the above code sample: I accessed the private variable `__randomVariable` of the parent class and of the subclass by writing `c._Parent__randomVariable`respectively `c._Child__randomVariable`. Its just an implementation trick Python uses to simulate private variables.